# One-hot-encoding using TransactionEncoder for lists with different number of elements

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to transform a transaction data into a one-hot encoded boolean array by using TransactionEncoder. However, I am not sure **how I can create an array with lists than have different number of elements.**

The transaction data looks something like this:

```
[['Apple', 'Beer', 'Rice', 'Chicken'],
['Apple', 'Beer', 'Rice'], ['Apple', 'Beer'], ['Apple', 'Bananas'], ['Milk', 'Beer', 'Rice',
'Chicken'], ['Milk', 'Beer', 'Rice'], ['Milk', 'Beer'], ['Apple', 'Bananas']]
```

Once I have the array called trans, I will try to use this code to convert it into a one-hot encoded boolean array:

```
te = TransactionEncoder()
data = te.fit_transform(trans)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = te.columns_)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ll = np.array([['Apple', 'Beer', 'Rice', 'Chicken'],
['Apple', 'Beer', 'Rice'], ['Apple', 'Beer'], ['Apple', 'Bananas'], ['Milk', 'Beer', 'Rice',
'Chicken'], ['Milk', 'Beer', 'Rice'], ['Milk', 'Beer'], ['Apple', 'Bananas']])

import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder

te2 = TransactionEncoder()
data2 = te2.fit_transform(ll)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = te2.columns_)
```